# Change the ImageView Layer

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-camera, surfaceview

Hye there I'm new to OpenCV but somehow good at Android! I have edited a code to change the Camera Background. For the Image to Set at the Background; I have been successfully done with it! Now the problem is that the ImageView comes over the camera screen! I just want my ImageView to come under the Camera I mean at the back of my camera! My code that I'm using is:

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import java.util.Random;

public class CustomCameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;
LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
private static final String TAG = "Svetlin SurfaceView";
private ImageView image;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                                                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myimage);
    image.setAlpha(150);


}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if(previewing){
        camera.stopPreview();
        previewing = false;
    }

    if (camera != null){
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            previewing = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_SUNSET);
    //ImageView overlay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    //overlay.bringToFront();
    camera.setParameters(params);
    // tryDrawing(holder);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    previewing = false;
}
 private void tryDrawing(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to draw...");

        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot draw onto the canvas as it's null");
        } else {
            drawMyStuff(canvas);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void drawMyStuff(final Canvas canvas) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Log.i(TAG, "Drawing...");
        canvas.drawRGB(255, 128, 128);
    }

  }
```

[image]
The White Image Should Come Behind the Camera as you can see in the screen shot!
    The thing is I just need to know that how can I change the Camera Background doing     so! Please give me Hints or any Idea so that can help me. THANKS IN ADVANCE!